# Access property by Index

Tags: c#, reflection

I need to access a property by an index or something similar. The reason why is explained in [this already answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7811586/131874). That answer uses Linq and I prefer something without that dependency. I have no control over the class.

```
public class myClass
{
    private string s = "some string";
    public string S
    {
        get { return s; }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        myClass c = new myClass();
        // I would like something similar
        // or same functionality
        string s = c["S"];
    }
}
```

Comment: LINQ is not a dependency; it's part of the core of .Net 3.5.  If you're stuck on .Net 2.0, you can trivially convert that answer to a couple of `foreach` loops with a dictionary.

Comment: Why the issue with LINQ?  It's been a standard feature for several versions now and is a powerful tool for expressing ideas concisely.  I'm 99% sure you can take the other answer and unwind it into other constructs, but why bother?

Comment: @SLaks: Even if you're stuck on .NET 2.0 you can get all the LINQ-to-Objects goodness with [LINQBridge](http://linqbridge.googlecode.com).

Comment: The resulting loops will be _much_ uglier and harder to maintain than the LINQ.

Comment: @Joe No issue with LINQ. It is just that solution got too verbose and it isn't even complete as I will have to add other filters.

Comment: @SLaks: Uglier? How? In VS2008 and newer, it will be the exact same code.

Comment: @AllonGuralnek: I was talking to him, not you.  (the loops for writing it without LINQ)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use (EDIT - as per comment):

```
string s = c.GetType().GetProperty ("S").GetGetMethod().Invoke (c, null).ToString();
```

It gives you the value of the (public) property named `S` of the the instance `c` regardless of the type of `c` and doesn't use LINQ at all although I must admit that I don't see why LINQ should be a problem...

Comment: Just added the ToString() method. It is the simplicity I asked for.

Answer (score 6):

As you have no control over the class you can use extension method and reflection to get property value by name:

```
static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static TResult Get<TResult>(this object @this, string propertyName)
    {
        return (TResult)@this.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(@this, null);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
class A
{
    public string Z
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int X
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A obj = new A();
        obj.Z = "aaa";
        obj.X = 15;

        Console.WriteLine(obj.Get<string>("Z"));
        Console.WriteLine(obj.Get<int>("X"));
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Comment: mmm, extension reflection property.  If you put that extension class on "object" you could pretty much add that property to any class at all couldn't you?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same thing by using a default property on your class and a collection.  Provided that you will always want strings, you could use the Dictionary class as your default property.

Then in the constructor you could intialize `myDictionary["s"] = "some string";`

You could then use the myClass as a collection, so myClass["s"] would return "some string".

Reflection is usually an indicator that you haven't created an API to do the job you need, if you have the code to modify then I recommend you use the default property.

See this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2b6akew6%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):