# Is there a way to reference the axis of a vector with an integer rather than x or y?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector

I have this code snippet and am looking to make it cleaner (this is c# for unity btw):

```
WallObj[] wallObjs = new WallObj[4];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    wallObjs[i] = transform.GetChild(i + 1).GetComponent<WallObj>();
}


wallObjs[0].setWallState((int)roomData.entryInfo.x);
wallObjs[1].setWallState((int)roomData.entryInfo.y);
wallObjs[2].setWallState((int)roomData.entryInfo.z);
wallObjs[3].setWallState((int)roomData.entryInfo.w);

foreach (WallObj wall in wallObjs)
{
    wall.adjacents(roomData.dunGrid, roomData.abstRoom);
}
```

Preferably, I want it to look something like:

```
WallObj[] wallObjs = new WallObj[4];
WallObj[] wallObjs = new WallObj[4];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    wallObjs[i] = transform.GetChild(i + 1).GetComponent<WallObj>();
    wallObjs[i].setWallState((int)roomData.entryInfo.i);
}

foreach (WallObj wall in wallObjs)
{
    wall.adjacents(roomData.dunGrid, roomData.abstRoom);
}
```

Comment: What type is `entryInfo`? Unity's `Vector4` type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity's [`Vector4`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector4.Index_operator.html) supports the index operator exactly as you describe.

Just use `(int)roomData.entryInfo[i]`.

That being said, pulling ints from float fields is a bit clunky and if you really aren't storing floats, you may consider implementing your own `Vector4Int` type that is backed with integers and supports the index operator.

Answer (score -1):

You may check [Access property by Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814591/access-property-by-index), it helps you to access *roomData .entryInfo* with for loop index.

But I think it's not a good idea to make code less readable for "**cleaner**"

Comment: reflection is pretty slow and this is unnecessary when Vector4 already offers this functionality.

Answer (score -2):

As far as I'm aware you can't pass in variables to access a specific component of a vector like you would with an array. One possible solution for your problem might be to have a method in the `wallObjs` class that does exactly what you're doing but a bit more hidden, but that depends on how much you need to do this. If you're only doing this once, you might just have to suck it up and deal with the ugly code, unfortunately.

Comment: If this vector implementation supports an indexer - which Unity vectors do - you can though ...

Comment: @derHugo I didn't know you could do that! Is there some documentation on it? I looked it up but didn't find anything, only old documentation from JavaScript.

Comment: @bnzzy See [Vector4 index operator documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector4.Index_operator.html)